# Caching with variation by RouteValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I have an Action that has diferent results depending on some route value.

ie `www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value1` is different then `www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value2`.

Is there any chance I can use `OutputCache` on the action About in controller Home with diferent output for `www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value1` and `www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value2`? I know I can use caching on model level, but I want to use `OutputCache` on the action.

**EDIT**

`www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value1` and then `www.mysite.com/Home/About/Value2` actually have different cache entries as stated by Levi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `[OutputCache()]` attribute to your About action method. If you want to vary it, you can use one of the parameters in the `OutputCache attribute`.

Comment: There is no parameter that takes into account RouteValues. Only variance by HttpParameters is supported (Querystring etc)

Comment: [OutputCache] already varies by RouteValues.  This just automatically happens since ASP.NET output caching is associated with a particular URL, and RouteValues are components within the URL.  So /Foo/Value1 will be cached separately from /Foo/Value2.