# Server Cache bug with OutputCache Attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

i'm a MVC beginner and today i met a strange problem:I want to use OutputCache to enable cache on one action.code like this:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=86400,VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        ViewBag.ID = id;

        return View();
    }
```

Notice that the "VaryByParam" property is "none",yes i want the server keep only one cache for the action, whatever the param was passed.
and the routing code is this:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

then i open the explore,the result is not what i want,for example i type:"http://localhost:27654/home/index/121212",the page come out and id"121212" was shown.but when i changed to "http://localhost:27654/home/index/12",and i see the page was changed ,id"12" was shown.

but if i refresh the page(para "id" not change),the datetime shown in the page didn't change,imply that asp.net has kept the cache VaryBy the "ID" para,not by my set.
what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198388/caching-with-variation-by-routevalue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518671/does-varybyparam-also-read-routedata-values

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's because you create another example of page by parameters predefined in route.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400,VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string some)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        ViewBag.ID = id;
        ViewBag.Some = some;
        return View();
    }
```

Route parameters can not be considered parameters for OutputCache. In my example `string some` is not the part of route, so if you will try the example the new version of cache will not be created if you cange parameter `some`

Also read this topic: [OutputCache Bug with VaryByParam="None" with MVC RC refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606915/outputcache-bug-with-varybyparam-none-with-mvc-rc-refresh)

Comment: thanks，does that mean in a "Http Get"scene,i can't use Route parameters,i must use queryString to pass parameters?in your example,i must type"http://localhost:27654/home/index?some=wawa"

Comment: it's mean that if any param defined in routes.MapRoute will change - the new example of cache will be created. /home/index/1 or /2 is route parameters, so it will be 2 cache items. QueryString parameters will not apply any influance to cached page, cause VaryByParam="none". Is it make sence?